# When the desktop bridge application uses the update API, disconnecting the network will cause the app to crash

Tags: c#, uwp, desktop-bridge

Using `StoreContext.CanSilentlyDownloadStorePackageUpdates` when the network is disconnected will cause the app to crash, and I try to use `Try-Catch` to fail to catch this exception.
In addition, when I use `StoreContext.TrySilentDownloadStorePackageUpdatesAsync` to download the update package, disconnecting the network at this time will also cause the APP to crash too.

Code snippet:

```
[System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions]
public bool CanSilentlyUpdate()
{
    try
    {
        //There will be an error:
        //    System.AccessViolationException :“Attempted to read or write protected memory. 
        //    This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.”
        return StoreContext.GetDefault().CanSilentlyDownloadStorePackageUpdates;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(ex);
        return false;
    }
}
```

The following is the error log in Event Viewer:

> Eventlog 1: Application: MyApp.exe Framework Version: v4.0.30319
> Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
> Exception Info: System.AccessViolationException at
> Windows.Services.Store.StoreContext.get_CanSilentlyDownloadStorePackageUpdates()

> Eventlog 2: Faulting application name: MyApp.exe, version: 1.0.0.0,
> time stamp: 0x96223b82 Faulting module name:
> Windows.ApplicationModel.Store.dll, version: 10.0.19041.329, time
> stamp: 0x92fa3e59 Exception code: 0xc0000005 Fault offset: 0x0009fcb0
> Faulting process id: 0x6d0c Faulting application start time:
> 0x01d6511c5d86de48 Faulting application path: C:\Program
> Files\WindowsApps\MyApp\MyApp.exe Faulting module path:
> C:\Windows\System32\Windows.ApplicationModel.Store.dll Report Id:
> d67098d6-39c7-4a02-a837-b523821c9ca2 Faulting package full name: MyApp
> Faulting package-relative application ID: App

> Eventlog 3： Application: MyApp.exe Framework Version: v4.0.30319
> Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
> Exception Info: exception code c0000005, exception address 7947FCB0
> Stack:

> Eventlog 4: Faulting application name: MyApp.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time
> stamp: 0x96223b82 Faulting module name:
> Windows.ApplicationModel.Store.dll, version: 10.0.19041.329, time
> stamp: 0x92fa3e59 Exception code: 0xc0000005 Fault offset: 0x0009fcb0
> Faulting process id: 0x36a0 Faulting application start time:
> 0x01d65131af3782e2 Faulting application path: C:\Program
> Files\WindowsApps\MyApp\MyApp.exe Faulting module path:
> C:\Windows\System32\Windows.ApplicationModel.Store.dll Report Id:
> 4a027389-345c-4f16-a605-276f2774c768 Faulting package full name: MyApp
> Faulting package-relative application ID: App

This kind of exception seems to be unable to be caught using managed code, what should I do?

Comment: Could you please share the code snippet that how you used the try-catch block? When do you call the CanSilentlyDownloadStorePackageUpdates method? Before or after the network is disabled?

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT Thanks for your reply, i've edited the question. It's very easy to reproduce this problem, i tried to use `[HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions]`, and it doesn't work.

Comment: When do you call the CanSilentlyDownloadStorePackageUpdates method? Before or after the network is disabled?

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT After the network is disabled.

Comment: If I call the CanSilentlyDownloadStorePackageUpdates method before I disable the network, it can return the correct value.

Comment: What about using the [unhandled exception event handler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.application.unhandledexception?view=winrt-19041), does it catch the exception?

Comment: No, I tried to use `Application.Dispatcher.UnhandledException` and `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException` to fail to catch the exception.

Comment: Hi Roy, I wrote a very simple demo and uploaded it to [onedriver](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ak6Tub3_nRs96F-9PUtS_XWYREIs?e=nP4nEj), you can directly reproduce the problem, if you can take a moment to help me look at it, it would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After discussing with other engineers, it looks like there is no other way to handle it.
This method should be running in the background so that you could not catch it in the UI thread. It essentially bypasses any chance dev has at handling the exception.

Our suggestion is that you need to check the network before calling this method and give a tip when calling this method to tell the user to keep network connection. And you could try to subscribe to [the NetworkInformation.NetworkStatusChanged Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.networking.connectivity.networkinformation.networkstatuschanged?view=winrt-19041) in your app.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. For `StoreContext.CanSilentlyDownloadStorePackageUpdates`, I can check the network status before calling, **but** for `StoreContext.TrySilentDownloadStorePackageUpdatesAsync`, I can ensure that the network is available before calling it. If the network is disabled during the update, then the app It still crashes. How can I avoid this problem?

Comment: As I mentioned in my reply, you might need to tell to the customer to keep the network connection during the process and if the network is disabled, just restart the app and try it again.

Comment: I understand, so may this problem be fixed in the future?